# Flavor-changing neutral current in the technicolor

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, beyond-the-standard-model, weak-interaction

What is the issue/problem of [Flavor-changing neutral current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavor-changing_neutral_current) in the technicolor model stated in [this lecture by  Nima Arkani-Hamed](https://youtu.be/dKVXxcbJ4YY?t=1563)?

- Why the technicolor model produces [Flavor-changing neutral current (FCNC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavor-changing_neutral_current)? but the technicolor model does not produce small enough FCNC?

Merci! <3

[image]

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavor-changing_neutral_current

Comment: Of course I read Wiki, if you know more, could you write an answer?